# Seeking contacts details

Tags: contact

I want to know the current contact details of an inventor on cultivated agarwood, US patent no. 7638145. Mr Blanchette R and Heuveling V. H. B, university of Minnesota.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to Google Patents for [US7638145](https://patents.google.com/patent/US7638145B2/en?oq=us%207638145) you will see a link to the [USPTO Patent Center](https://patentcenter.uspto.gov/applications/10912017/attorney?application=) for this patent. You won't find the inventor contact info here, but you can find the contact info for the patent firm and attorneys. The firm information is:

VIKSNINS HARRIS PADYS MALEN LLP
7900 International Drive, Suite 410
Bloomington, MN 55425
UNITED STATES

There is also the phone numbers for the patent attorneys at that firm. One of them should be able to direct you to the inventors.

This is the formal way of getting information about a US patent. The informal way is to do a simple google search. I did this and found that Robert Blanchette is associated with the University of Minnesota. [**Here is his website with contact information**](https://plpa.cfans.umn.edu/people/robert-blanchette).

Also be advised that that patent seems to be expired as its status is listed as:

> Patent Expired Due to NonPayment of Maintenance Fees Under 37 CFR
> 1.362 01/31/2022